# How to make a fragment show up in the Android Studio layout designer?

Tags: android, android-studio

When using the layout designer in Android Studio, custom classes that I create which extend the `View` class show up in the layout designer (picture relevant)

[image]

Is there a similar way to make custom classes appear that extend the `Fragment` class?

My use case is that I'm developing a library which I will distribute to our clients. I want it to be ***as easy as possible*** for someone to use this library to place a video player in their own application. I discovered that *fragments* may be exactly what I need -- something which has a defined appearance, can be trivially dropped into someone else's layout, yet is able to manage its own state, perform business logic, and listen to life cycle events (for the sake of cleaning up video buffers, stopping timers, and de-allocating resources)

However when I tried switching from using a `View` to using a `Fragment`, it didn't show up in the palette to be dragged and dropped into my app. While not ***absolutely and incredibly super-duper necessary***, I was really hopeful that I could maintain that as an ease-of-use feature.

Comment: Fragments don't show up in the Palette tool by default, and I'm not certain that there's a way to get them there. The technique that you are describing (drag and drop a fragment into a layout) is for static fragments, and more often we use dynamic fragments (`FragmentTransaction`, etc.). Having them in the Palette is not a bad idea, though -- if you don't get a solution here, you might consider filing a feature request.

Comment: @CommonsWare Could you shed any light on why having a "smart" View is frowned upon so heavily in the Android community, and why everyone says that you should put all logic into a View Controller? If I just put my business logic into a View then I feel like I could get the best of both worlds in terms of usability for my library.

Comment: That would be a fine separate Stack Overflow question. :-) In a nutshell, reliability and testability become seriously problematic when you pile too much business logic into a `View`. Partly, that's due to the nature of Android's `View` system, and it's why Jetpack Compose is going to be revisiting the whole concept. But a lot of it is just reflective of more modern software development, and AFAIK is not unique to Android. Loosely-coupled components are easier to write, easier to mock, easier to test, easier to replace, etc.

Comment: BTW, I went ahead and [filed the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132686263).